# what changes to be made in android manifest while using implicit intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

I am creating an application which searches a given string on different search engines depending on the search engine you select. I am using an implicit intent to get the search string in local browser and search the string. I am new to android and don't know if I have to add something in manifest for the intent. I have added the permission to use the internet.

Comment: read this http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Comment: Post some code and what is the issue you are having.